# Laravel Cashier - Prevent duplicated Payment Methods

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier

I'm trying to update the payment method of a subscription. I collect the card information using Stripe's js (using a provided setup intent). Then I send the payment method id, provided by Stripe's js, to Laravel to actually update the User's default payment method.

Now, the problem is I want to prevent the User to insert duplicated cards, and the only way to prevent that would be to retrieve all the user current payment methods (`$user->paymentMethods();`), and check if any of those has the same fingerprint of the one I'm adding as default.

To get the fingerprint of the new payment method I'd need to get the Stripe PaymentMethod object for the id provided by the Stripe's js. The Cashier method to do that would be `$user->findPaymentMethod(id)`.

The problem is that the payment id is not yet added to the User payments methods, so `$user->findPaymentMethod($request->payment_method);` fails because that payment method does not belong to $user.

The only solution I can think of would be to first add the new payment method, then check for duplicates and remove them ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you’ve already found the best approach of adding the method to the user and then looking to see if there are any duplicated fingerprints, even if it is a little inconvenient.

Reviewing the Cashier documentation doesn’t show any obvious way to access the PaymentMethod before it’s attached to the user.  It may be worth reaching out to the Laravel devs to see if there is functionality that would make this flow easier to accomplish.